# SwiftUI Chart expanded

Tags: ios, swiftui, charts, swiftui-charts

I am working with charts in SwiftUI, which include LineMark, PointMark, and AreaMark. Additionally, there is an annotation in the chart. However, I am facing difficulties in adjusting the chart width according to the screen width. The output I am currently getting is:

[image]

Part of my code:

```
       var chartGradient: LinearGradient {
    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.accentColor, .clear]),
                   startPoint: .top,
                   endPoint: .bottom)
}

var chartData: [ChartData] = [
    ChartData(day: "Day 1", value: 40),
    ChartData(day: "Day 10", value: 50)
]

func chartView() -> some View {
    Chart(chartData) { data in
        LineMark(x: .value("Day", data.day),
                 y: .value("Value", data.value))
            .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
    
        PointMark(x: .value("Day", data.day),
                  y: .value("Value", data.value))
            .annotation(position: .top,
                        alignment: .bottom,
                        spacing: 10) {
                Text("")
                    .font(.body)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 12)
                    .padding(.vertical, 4)
                    .background(.accentColor)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
            }
        AreaMark(x: .value("Day", data.day),
                 y: .value("Value", data.value))
            .foregroundStyle(chartGradient)
            .opacity(0.3)
    }
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 150)
    .chartXAxis(.hidden)
    .chartYAxis(.hidden)
}
```

[image]

Screenshot of the chart without zooming: [image]

Comment: What did you try? **"I did not adjust the chart according to the width of the screen."** why didn't you?

Comment: I couldn't do it

Comment: Are you setting an explicit frame for the chart? And are you able to provide a screenshot of the chart without zooming in?

Comment: Yes, I am specifying a frame. I have attached a screenshot.

Comment: Can you add all the code related to the chart? (frame,...)

Comment: I added everything related to the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your X-Axis data is a `String`, the chart isn't able evaluate the order of your `ChartData` array and places it in the middle. To solve this:

1. Convert your `ChartData` to use a `Comparable` type for the day property instead of `String`, example: `Double`, `Int`... **Note that this will start your chart at the point 0, not the minimum day of your array:**
   [image]
2. To center your chart, you need to use the `chartXScale` modifier which will let you specify the exact range of your array's day property. *i.e: minDay...maxDay.*:

   ```
   .chartXScale(domain: 1...10) //using your example data
   ```
3. Now you can use `.padding(.horizontal, spacing)` to configure the space around the chart.

**Example using `Int`:**

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        chartView()
    }
    var chartData: [ChartData] = [
        ChartData(day: 1, value: 40),
        ChartData(day: 10, value: 50)
    ]
    var xAxisRange: ClosedRange<Int> { //Compute the chartXScale dynamically
        let dayRange = chartData.reduce(into: (min: Int.max, max: Int.min)) { partialResult, item in
            partialResult.min = min(item.day, partialResult.min)
            partialResult.max = max(item.day, partialResult.max)
        }
        return dayRange.min...dayRange.max
    }
    func chartView() -> some View {
        Chart(chartData) { data in
            LineMark(x: .value("Day", data.day),
                     y: .value("Value", data.value))
                .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
        
            PointMark(x: .value("Day", data.day),
                      y: .value("Value", data.value))
                .annotation(position: .top,
                            alignment: .bottom,
                            spacing: 10) {
                    Text("")
                        .font(.body)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 12)
                        .padding(.vertical, 4)
                        .background(.accentColor)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                }
            AreaMark(x: .value("Day", data.day),
                     y: .value("Value", data.value))
                .foregroundStyle(chartGradient)
                .opacity(0.3)
        }
        .frame(height: 150)
        .chartXScale(domain: xAxisRange)
        .chartXAxis(.hidden)
        .chartYAxis(.hidden)
        .padding(.horizontal, 40)
    }
}

struct ChartData: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let day: Int
    let value: Int
}
```

**Result:**
[image]